# Setting Thread Culture in VB6

Tags: multithreading, vb6, culture

Is there a VB6 equivalent of the following C# code?

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")

Comment: Make a winapi call to SetThreadLocale().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Windows API function [`SetThreadLocale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead

Answer (score 1):

There is no in built multi-lingual support in VB6, to internationalize VB 6 you need to use resource files and translate your app for each language and loadresstring for all your strings. VB 6 does have unicode support when using Microsoft Forms 2.0 controls (fm20.dll).