# How to custom set regional settings for a single application?

Tags: .net, vb6, internationalization

I need to somehow "internationalize" an application written in VB6. This I18n is just for a few countries and **the users are aware** that, for instance, they are supposed to use the American decimal separator `.` instead of a comma `,`, for instance. Dates are also a big common problem.

My approach if using .NET would be to set the CultureInfo of the main thread when the application starts to en-US. However, in VB6, I'm not able to do that (from what I know).

Did someone face this problem before? What is the best way to solve it? Simplest way, from my POV, would be to override the user regional settings for my application process, but I don't know how to do it in VB6...

Edit: What I would like at this point would be a way to override the user-defined Regional Settings by mine, just for my process

Edit #2: I tried this but it didn't work (my settings are in pt-PT, decimal separator is a comma, I was expecting to get a dot (en-US)):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    SetAmerican

    Dim test As Double
    test = 1.23
    MsgBox (test)

    Unload Me
End Sub

Declare Function SetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long) As Long
Public Const LANG_EN_US = 1033

Public Sub SetAmerican()
    Call SetThreadLocale(LANG_EN_US)
End Sub
```

Comment: See if anything in [here helps](http://www.bing.com/search?q=internationalization+in+vb6&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH)

Comment: Yes, see the answers on this [duplicate question "setting thread culture in VB6"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733916/setting-thread-culture-in-vb6)

Comment: @MarkJ didn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: @Żubrówka what do you mean did not work? can you show some code or document what does not work?

Comment: @DavidePiras (Please check my question)

Comment: Val() and Str$() offer locale-blind conversions for numeric values (decimal point is always period).  Date String conversions can usually be managed with a couple of simple functions.

Comment: Oh, and "a way to override the user-defined Regional Settings by mine, just for my process" is the complete opposite of the "Best way to handle regional settings in VB6". The best way is to honour and accept the users regional settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem today (a 3rd party program bug) and this is how I fixed:
Just before I run my program I set at `HKCU\Control Panel\International` registry the decimal and thousand symbols.

After start this program, it was safe to return back to original settings (I did't had to wait it to finish, which took a couple of minutes).

You could even wrap in a batch file like:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sDecimal  /d . /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sThousand /d , /f

start PrograminhaMaroto.exe    
ping 127.0.0.1 /n 2 > NULL

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sDecimal  /d , /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sThousand /d . /f
```

Answer (score 0):

We had to do some localization for a VB6 app for Brazil.  The easiest way I found to test was to go into (Windows 7) 
`Control Panel->Clock, Language, and Region->Change the date,time, or number format`

[image: Region and Language Settings]

and change the Format.  Once I did this, the numeric and date formats changed accordingly and the localization info I entered showed up where coded.

Note: On Windows XP, it's `Control Panel->Regional and Language Options`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: There's nothing about setting different settings for one application here.

Comment: @JohnB.Lambe It answered the question as written...12 years ago. Question was edited and changed quite a bit many years after the answer was posted.