# VB6 - converting string to double using specific culture?

Tags: vb6, localization, type-conversion

I am a long time C# developer and have had to look at some VB6 code lately. After some digging, we found out that, somewhere, somehow, we are storing a number as a string. Now we are reading it back and our code is not handling culture differences very well. Here is an example:

```
Dim text as String
Dim myVal as Double
Set text = "1,123456"
'This sets the value of myVal to 1123456 on our system - incorrect
myVal = text

Set text = "1.123456"
'This sets the value of myVal to 1.123456 on our system - correct
myVal = text
```

Keeping in mind that this is VB6 and NOT VB.NET, are there any built-in methods, functions, whatever, that can convert a string to a double using a particular culture?
Or at the very least, hinting to the conversion that we may be dealing with a different format?

We are still digging how the value gets written and see if we can reverse engineer the process to give us a consistent result. However, our customer(s) already has(have) data in one format or the other (or both, we are checking...), so a proper conversion algorithm or implementation would be a better answer at this point.

Comment: You're going to need some context of where the number came from to know how to convert it. For a very simplistic method, you could just replace , with a . and pass it to `Val()`. Of course if you get 12,345.67 then you're screwed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used this quick and dirty function in the past to get a double from a text. Here in Argentina, people sometimes use the point and sometimes the comma to separate decimal values, so this function is ready to accept both formats. If only one punctuation is present, it's assumed that it's the decimal separator.

```
function ConvertDBL( texto )
    dim retval, SepDecimal, SepMiles
    If texto = "" then texto = "0"
    retval = replace(trim(texto), " ", "")
    If cdbl("3,24") = 324 then
        SepDecimal = "."
        SepMiles = ","
    else
        SepDecimal = ","
        SepMiles = "."
    end if  
    If InStr( Retval, SepDecimal ) > 0 then
        If InStr( Retval, SepMiles ) > 0 then
            If InStr( Retval, SepDecimal ) > InStr( Retval, SepMiles ) then
                Retval = replace( Retval, SepMiles, "" )
            else
                Retval = replace( Retval, SepDecimal, "" )
                Retval = replace( Retval, SepMiles, SepDecimal )
            end if
        end if      
    else
        Retval = replace( Retval, SepMiles, SepDecimal )
    end if
    ConvertDbl = cdbl( retval ) 
end function
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. While I may not use it as-is, your detection mechanism of trying to convert "3,24" to detect what culture you are in is just genius! Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot choose an arbitrary culture by passing a culture object like you can in .Net. You can choose:

- Functions which always use the current regional settings. `CStr`, `Format`, `CDbl` etc. Implicit conversions (like the ones in your question) also use the current regional settings.
- Functions which always use USA regional settings (similar to the .Net invariant culture). `Str`, `Val`

Usually the current regional settings are taken from Control Panel. There are [rumours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733916/setting-thread-culture-in-vb6) that you can call `SetThreadLocale` to change the regional settings from code at runtime - never tried it myself.

Comment: thanks for the additional info. We aware of such limitations. However, for some reason, data ended up in different format into our customer's database.We do know that some of users prefer to use en-US as their culture, eventhough they are not in the US. So, basically, we need to be able to parse either "1,2345" or "1.2345" as 1.2345d in VB6. Yes, we are aware that in certain cultures, those 2 notations mean something totally different. But in our particular situation, we are fairly confident that only decimal numbers were stored in the database. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Try to detect the format & then process accordingly? Something like this? bDot = (Instr(test, ".")>0) bComma=(Instr(test,",")>0) If bDot And bComma Then Err.Raise vbObjectError+512, "unable to process value with dot and comma" If bComma Then test = Replace(test, ",", ".") End If value = Val(test)

Comment: you are correct. We can handle most cases with Eduardo's code. The tricky case is 1,234 where you can't assume it's 1.234. It could be 1234 in cultures that use "," as the digit grouping. We want to understand how the inconsistent data made it into the database so we can make a more educated guess at to whether we should assume 1,234 always means 1.234 or we have cases were that could mean 1234. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic tested works very fast and efficient.

Step 1: Conversion from a string to a value representation.

Step 2: Conversion from a value representation to a double integer value.

```
Dim Str as String
Dim mValue as double
str = "100,10"

mValue = CDbl(Val(str))
```

---